# Kotlin and Android Studio IF statement with Booleans

Tags: android, kotlin

I just started learning Kotlin with Android Studio, I'm following some guide on youtube and guy didn't explain good enough for one beginner so if some1 can help me out to understand this if statement.
Btw this is simple calculator app.

```
    var lastNumeric : Boolean = false
    var lastDot : Boolean = false

fun onDigit(view: View){
        tvInput.append((view as Button).text)
        lastNumeric = true

fun onDecimalPoint(view: View){
        if (lastNumeric && !lastDot) {
                tvInput.append(".")
                lastNumeric = false
                lastDot = true
```

After we set both vars to `false`, when I press any number button I set `lastNumeric` to `true` then in if statement `lastNumeric` is `true` and `!lastDot` is also `true` so it pass to next line that is decimal point. After that `lastNumeric` is again `false` but `lastDot` is now `true`.
At that point I have `lastNumeric - false` and `lastDot - true (but because "!" -> lastDot is false)` so my if statement is now `false` forever and I can't add decimal point untill I set it on `false (!lastDot - true)` at some part of code right?

I'm really sorry for this confusing explanation, I tried my best. If someone can confirm that my opinion is right or if it's not can you guys explain me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right && means **and** in logic it is just true if all variables are true you understand right it will not go inside the block if both (lastnumeric and reverse lastdot) are true it is good for you to learn blocks in a good way because you will use them all of your codes    I wish you success

Comment: Thanks mate! It was really confusing at first had to really go through it few times with print to understand it haha.

Comment: Yeah we all were the same when I started to learn python I could not sleep because I could not understand something but you will see after kotlin you can learn any language easily in a few days but you should work hard and force yourself.

Comment: Yeah mate Python is so much easier to learn, but learning Python gave me some basics so I can at least understand Kotlin code to some point :D